# Compile release and debug at the same time for a C++ project

Tags: c++, ninja

Is it possible to compile release and debug versions at the same time (different tabs) in a C++ project?

I've tried doing this, with both [SCons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCons) and Ninja, and I had no problems. I worry that something I'm not aware of is happening and there will be downstream problems...

Comment: Rather unclear as phrased... It is harmless as long as you build debug and release versions in different folders, but it could lead to mixing debug and release intermediate files if you use the same folder for both.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simultaneous builds using different configurations are done all the time. (Well, perhaps not *simultaneous*, but certainly one right after the other.) In Visual Studio, there is a built-in command to do this called "Batch Build". Presumably other IDEs have something similar, and certainly MAKE files support building multiple configurations at one go.

The thing to remember is, like Serge said, to keep the output files in separate folders. That should be the default in your build environment or IDE. There is never a reason to mix these up. Keep the Debug and Release output (binaries, symbols, temp files, etc.) separated.